# My table in word document got compressed

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice

I have created a table in a word document, but when I closed the file and re-opened the cells got compressed.
[image]

But my table had proper content earlier :

[image]

I tried expanding it sevral times , but I am not able to expand it properly. How to fix this issue with my word document.

Comment: I am not sure why this occur.  Can you make a new table that is correct and copy the contents to the new table?

Comment: @John, I have created a lengthy table that took a very long time, so trying to restore the the old data.

Comment: Try repairing the document . Word, Open -> Open and Repair. Make sure the document is backed up first.

Comment: @John, sorry I am not seeing the open and repair option

Comment: Yes, probably because Word does not see the table as being damaged (that is compressed not equal to damage). I was not able to discern that from here.

Comment: Try all the steps in this document ...   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/damaged-documents-in-word   .... particularly trying a new Normal template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tick Fit text in the table settings.
[image]